# C++ invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]

Tags: c++, char, constants, compile-time

WARNING: Extremely limited knowledge of C++ and coding in general. Please refrain from advanced terminology.

```
for ( i = 0; i < answer.size(); ++i) {
            if (guess == answer.at(i)) {                            //to display correct letters in answerDisplay
                answerDisplay.replace( (2 * i), 1, answer.at(i) );
                correctGuesses += 1;
            }
```

Given: answerDisplay and answer are strings.

When I run my program there is a compile-time error at the third line of what I've posted saying:

```
invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’ [-fpermissive]
```

What's the problem? How can I fix it? All other posts with this error talked about pointer characters but I don't know what those are.

Comment: @Alec Pflaumer Give us the whole code with declarations.

Comment: As Richard Rublev said, it is hard for us to deduce the reason for that error, because the error message itself refers to "char" and "const char *", which are some data types that occur in your code. We need those data types. Somewhere in your code, "answer", "guess", "answerDispla.replace" and "correctGuesses" are declared, i.e. they are mentioned next to a type. We need those lines. Also, the error message usually refers to a certain line of code. Can you tell us, which one it is? Usually, it is of course a nice thing to only give us the information we need, but in this case, we need more.

Comment: What kind of answer do you expect?

Answer (score 3):

Pointer characters are they way plain strings are implemented in C and C++. In C++ you have the nice class `std::string`, but string literals are still array of characters. And arrays in C and C++ can be seen as pointers.

For example, `"hello"` is of type `const char[6]` (5 characters plus the ending NUL), but it can be trivially converted to `const char *`, and that in turn can be converted to `std::string`.

In line 3, the only relevant code is a call to the member function `std::string::replace()`. There are a lot of overrides of this function (different sets of parameters to be used), but the one the compiler is trying to use is this one:

```
string& replace (size_t pos,  size_t len,  const char* s);
```

As you can see, it takes two numbers and a `const char *` (an old-string/char-array). But you are passing as third parameter  `answer.at(i)` that is of type `char`. Hence the error:

```
invalid conversion from ‘char’ to ‘const char*’
```

Solution? You can build a string from that char:

```
answerDisplay.replace( (2 * i), 1, std::string(1, answer.at(i))
```

Or you can get a substring of the original string instead of a plain character.

```
answerDisplay.replace( (2 * i), 1, answer.substr(i, 1))
```

Comment: Better than my punt on an answer, plus one.